# How do I add multiple conditions

Tags: discord.js

How do I add @ conditions inside an if statement in discord.js
here's my code:

```js
if (message.content === "/roll1"  &&  player1 = "1") {
     message.channel.send("no game is running")
}
```

Comment: By the way, `player1 = "1"` will set the variable `player1` to have a string value of `"1"` as it is currently. You probably meant to use `player1 == "1"` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean mentions?
In that case, we can simply check if there are no user mentions inside of a message by defining the mentioned user and using an if statement to figure out whether a user object for him was actually found. We can do that by typing:

```
const user = message.mentions.users.first() // gets the first mentioned user inside of a message
if (!user) return message.reply('Please mention a user!') // Will return the command if no user was mentioned or the user object could not be found.
```